# Controlling external appliances with a microcontroller by replacing switch with relay

Tags: microcontroller, switches, relay

I am working on a custom school project where I want to control a coffee machine's power using a micro-controller.

I have never worked with interfacing to external appliances like this before so please bear with me as I describe my question.

My idea for this problem is to replace the switch with some sort of relay configuration, in order to control the power flow with my micro-controller's output. I've done some research and believe I am working with an SPDT switch. It has 3 pins, the first pin connected directly to the power line, the second pin connected to a heating element, and the third pin connected to the heating element and ground.

I've also found a relay at my local store that I believe should work (please tell me if I'm wrong). It can be found here: http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70133525.

I am able to produce a 5V output from my micro-controller which I plan to use as the control signal for the relay.

This being the first time I've worked on this type of application, I want to make sure I understand how to transfer the wires from the switch to the relay correctly before I go about testing my configuration.

Here's the coffee machine's switch and wires:
[image: coffee machine wiring]

and here is the relay's schematic:

[image: relay schematic]

From what I understand the wiring should be as such:

1. Single black wire (top pin of switch)
2. Black and blue wire (bottom pin of switch)
3. Control signal from micro-controller (providing 5V)
4. Red wire (middle pin of switch)
5. Ground (provided by micro-controller)

Would this configuration be correct? Please let me know if I should try anything else or if any additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your picture and the wire colors I see, I have a question.  Does the switch light up when the coffee pot is turned ON?  If so, what you have is a SPST (Single Pole Single Throw) switch with built-in indicator.

The blue wire is *usually* neutral and the brown wire is *usually* hot or live.  The middle switch terminal is usually the common point of the switch and the indicator.

Because this is a coffee pot, expect some significant current.  The solid-state relay that Some Hardware Guy showed a picture of is a good choice.  Be aware that it probably requires a heatsink.  Pick the heatsink size by assuming that the SSR will drop 1V at whatever current your load consumes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a relay try this one from amazon it's pretty easy to use.   [relay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HIU8TSK)

[image: relay]

Be careful playing around with high voltages like this, don't touch anything while the power is on or when anything is plugged in.